# WhatsApp web without camera

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

Is it possible to load WhatsApp web without camera?. My front and back camera are broken and I am not able to load WhatsApp web without it. 
Anyone knows if it is possible to load it without the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, you need to scan with WhatsApp. When you scan the QR code you get a session ID. WhatsApp send that ID to their server to enable a session in your browser.